# Using css grid, how do I get SHORT<div> text to wrap on an earlier space instead of slightly overflowing on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow, css-grid

The following problem appears on my (iPhone) mobile. My text (with relatively short words separated by spaces (not `&nbsp;`s)) is slightly overflowing before wrapping. I want it to wrap without overflowing. In other words, I want it to choose an earlier space to terminate one line (line break on) before wrapping to the next line.

I'm doing this with a CSS grid.

I apologize that the CSS is a bit lengthy. In my desperation, I've used a variety of found resets that I don't completely understand. My code is here: https://codepen.io/Photog/pen/rNGEbKL

```css
* {
  font-size: 100%;
}


/* reset / initialize */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Define variables for colors */

:root {
  --bgnormal: black;
  --fgnormal: white;
}


/* ****************************************** */


/* Eric Meyer's reset.css: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/


/* alphabetized */

a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
applet,
article,
aside,
audio,
b,
big,
blockquote,
body,
canvas,
caption,
center,
cite,
code,
dd,
del,
details,
dfn,
div,
dl,
dt,
em,
embed,
fieldset,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
form,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
header,
hgroup,
html,
i,
iframe,
img,
ins,
kbd,
label,
legend,
li,
mark,
menu,
nav,
object,
ol,
output,
p,
pre,
q,
ruby,
s,
samp,
section,
small,
span,
strike,
strong,
sub,
summary,
sup,
table,
tbody,
td,
tfoot,
th,
thead,
time,
tr,
tt,
u,
ul,
var,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* ******************************************** */

body {
  font-size: calc(0.75em + 1vmin);
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
}

article,
aside,
div,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
form,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
header,
hr,
li,
main,
nav,
p,
section,
ul {
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Arial, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
}


/* ********************* */

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 10% 10% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  align-items: start;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 96vw;
  /* 96% of viewport */
}

.grid-item-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-4 {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

[class^='grid-item'] {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item-2">
    If&nbsp;you're interested in purchasing, displaying or discussing my photographs, please contact me. I&nbsp;usually respond within three days. I'd&nbsp;be delighted to hear from you and know what you think.
    <br><br> I am available for critique sessions, workshops and presentations where I share my experience, creative process and techniques as a photographer and curator.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a padding inside `grid-item-2` container and use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` so that it would wrap the text without breaking the word itself but through spaces. More on wrapping [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text).

```css
* {
  font-size: 100%;
}


/* reset / initialize */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Define variables for colors */

:root {
  --bgnormal: black;
  --fgnormal: white;
}


/* ****************************************** */


/* Eric Meyer's reset.css: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/


/* alphabetized */

a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
applet,
article,
aside,
audio,
b,
big,
blockquote,
body,
canvas,
caption,
center,
cite,
code,
dd,
del,
details,
dfn,
div,
dl,
dt,
em,
embed,
fieldset,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
form,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
header,
hgroup,
html,
i,
iframe,
img,
ins,
kbd,
label,
legend,
li,
mark,
menu,
nav,
object,
ol,
output,
p,
pre,
q,
ruby,
s,
samp,
section,
small,
span,
strike,
strong,
sub,
summary,
sup,
table,
tbody,
td,
tfoot,
th,
thead,
time,
tr,
tt,
u,
ul,
var,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* ******************************************** */

body {
  font-size: calc(0.75em + 1vmin);
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
}

article,
aside,
div,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
form,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
header,
hr,
li,
main,
nav,
p,
section,
ul {
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Arial, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
}


/* ********************* */

.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 10% 10% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  align-items: start;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 96vw;
  /* 96% of viewport */
}

.grid-item-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  padding: 3rem;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

.grid-item-4 {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}

[class^='grid-item'] {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item-2">
    If&nbsp;you're interested in purchasing, displaying or discussing my photographs, please contact me. I&nbsp;usually respond within three days. I'd be delighted to hear from you and know what you think.
    <br><br> I am available for critique sessions, workshops and presentations where I share my experience, creative process and techniques as a photographer and curator.
  </div>

</div>
```